# Force a USB device to use a certain drive letter

Tags: windows, usb, usb-flash-drive, drive-letter

Wnen I connected a friend's USB to my computer, it took a letter that used to be for my USB device. Now my USB doesn't use the same letter as before, even after a reboot.

Is it possible to force it to go back to the same letter as before?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Start | Control Panel | Administrative Tools | Computer Management

- Click on "Disk Management"
- Select the USB drive in the list
- Right-click and "Change Drive Letters and Paths..."
- Assign a different, unused drive letter.

Comment: An alternative way to get to the "Disk Management" utility (at least on XP) is to go to the run box and enter in diskmgmt.msc and hit enter.

Comment: Thanks @quickcel. I really need to make a list of file names for the various applets. I have a few memorized, but not nearly as many as are available. ;)